# No-site-packages error when installing Hue with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, hue

I got `no-site-packages` error while trying to install hue on my local system.
 Is there anyone who knows how to solve such an issue?

This is the commands I ran:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:cloudera/hue.git
```

`$ sudo apt-get install` (the ap list shows in https://github.com/cloudera/hue)

Enter Hue

```
$ make apps
```

[image: error messages]

I tried the solution which is provided in Google groups, but the same issue still keeps showing up:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip

$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv

$ cd /usr/lib/python2.7

$ sudo ln -s plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.py
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Weird, this seems to be the exact same problem as https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1672.

Did you install setuptools 0.6?
pip installs python-setuptools (0.6.34-0ubuntu1)

Comment: $ pip install python-setuptools

Downloading/unpacking python-setuptools

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-setuptools

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for python-setuptools

Comment: You are hitting this issue: http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/